# How can I find wedge product of tensors?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensors

I have two tensors - $A_{k}$ and $B_{lm}$. How can I find wedge product of them? Wedge product of two tensors $\alpha$ $(p, 0)$ and $\beta$ $(q, 0)$ is defined as $$\alpha \wedge \beta = \frac{(p + q)!}{p! q!} \text{Alt} (\alpha \otimes \beta)$$, where $Alt$ is antisymmetrisation of tensor.

The result I got is $A_k B_{lm} + A_l B_{mk} + A_m B_{kl}$, but it's apparently wrong according to my teacher :(

Comment: Ok, you're not really making your context clear: what is "Alt"? I can guess that it might be the image of that tensor in an exterior power... But, also, "outer product" is an ambiguous phrase. Apparently you mean it to be ("simply"?) "wedge product"... But/and, what is the relation of all your symbols? $\alpha$ versus $A$, and so on? Can you clarify? :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Sorry, English isn't my first language so I'm not sure about namings, but I tried...